# How to compute symbolic/numeric Fourier transforms in SageMath, and define a function out of it?

Tags: sage

I am new to SageMath and Python and I am writing simple Jupyter notebooks to learn them. I have experience in Mathematica and I am trying to mimic what I can do in a Mathematica notebook, to understand if I can migrate to SageMath for my work.

I would like to compute a symbolic Fourier transform of a real function *f(x)* and define a SageMath symbolic function out of it. In Mathematica I would write

`foo[k_] := FourierTransform[f[x],x,k]`

and this would do the job. In SageMath 9.0, I started with

```
from sympy import fourier_transform as ft
from sympy import inverse_fourier_transform as ift
```

and then

```
g(x) = exp(-x**2)
exp_ft(k) = ft(g(x),x,k)
```

which seems to work properly; I evaluated `exp_ft(k)` at certain values, I differentiated it, plotted it, checked that the variable `k` is local by evaluating `exp_ft(t)` and getting the same functional expression with `t` instead of `k`. The first question is: is this the correct/best way to perform such operation is SageMath?

In Mathematica, I can also define a function as

`foo[k_?NumericQ] = FourierTransform[f[x],x,k]`

to improve efficiency. Is there any way to do this in SageMath? In other words, are the delayed `:=` and non-delayed `=` assignment present in SageMath/Python, and is there the possibility to write conditional statements in the arguments of a function, as it can be done in Mathematica (see above)?

Also, if I compute the Fourier transform of *cos(x)*,

`ft(cos(x),x,k)`

the result is 0. Isn't this wrong? The result should be the sum of two Dirac deltas. A similar issue shows up if I compute the inverse Fourier transform of 1, which is the Dirac delta. I get an implicit expression, not the delta. However, if I compute the Fourier transform of the Dirac delta, I get 1. How to deal with this?

Thanks in advance for the help!